# Different Output on different machines of this code

Tags: c, mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 1) goto label;
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    for (j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d", j);
        label: ;
    }
}
```

this c code outputs 0 on my system while on others it outputs 01234 what can i do so that it also displays 01234 on my system. i am using ms vs code.

Comment: This code invokes undefined behavior because when you jump to `label`, `j` is uninitialized. If you want your code to print `01234` on all systems, then just `printf("01234");`

Comment: jumping with `goto` inside a `for` loop is asking for trouble

Comment: Why do you use `goto` at all ? It's a bad practice in most (if not all) cases.

Comment: @wohlstad didn't you experiment when learning C?

Comment: @0___________ yes, but I don't see how the example in the question is useful or productive for learning the langage properly. And I wouldn't advocate the usage of `goto`.

Comment: @wohlstad `properly` is very subjective. You need to experiment `improperly` to learn the language `properly`

Comment: Good judgment comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable `j` before your `goto` otherwise you invoke undefined behaviour.

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 1) goto label;
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    for (j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d", j);
        label: ;
    }
}
```

> Different Output on different machines of this code

If you have it - look for the ***U***ndefined ***B***ehaviour (UB) in your code :)

## ALSO:

`main` function **has** to return `int`. It is defined by the C standard. You do not need to have `return` statement in this function

Comment: You'll need to initialize `j = 0` to get the desired output of `01234`

Comment: Please note that this is UB because `j` is a local variable which is uninitialized _and didn't have its address taken_. Had the code been `int i, j; int*k = &j; ...` then it would merely be unspecified behavior to access `j`.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

As others mentioned when the program jumps to label the variable `j` is not initialized yet, so it just doesn't know the value of `j`.

Also before `1` and `2` get printed in the first loop, you exit it by using `goto` and jumping to the second loop, and after that, you are essentially reading the value of whatever happens to be in the memory location assigned to `j` at that moment. So the value could be anything, and it's essentially garbage data that you're using in the second loop's condition or even in the print statement.

So with this overall structure, you generally can't achieve `01234` as the output.

### Possible Solution depending on What you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i == 2) {
      goto label;
    }
  }

label:

  for (j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
    printf("%d", j);
  }
}
```

You can make sure `j` will be initialized by putting the `label` before the second loop to make sure `j` will be initialized before the loop runs.

And overall try to avoid using `goto` as long as you haven't mastered it and how it will affect the behavior of the program.

Comment: Avoid `goto` even after you've mastered it's behaviour.  That's not the same as "never use `goto`" — there are legitimate uses for it.  But avoid it when you can, which is most of the time.  (See also [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/15168)). And jumping from one loop to another is _not_ a good use case for a `goto`.